# Extension Method for Entity Framework 4

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, expression-trees

I use an extension method for entity Framwork entity:

```
    <Extension()>
    Public Function IsExcluded(ByVal item As AnomalyProduct) As Boolean

        Dim result As Boolean

        If (item.WholesalerProductCode IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (item.WholesalerProductCode = _excludedChar) Then
            result = True
        Else
            result = False
        End If

        Return result

    End Function
```

I want to get a list of entity depending of the Extension Method result:

```
    Private Function HasPacksExcluded(ByVal contextId As Guid) As Boolean

        Dim result As Boolean
        Dim context As ContextManager.ContextData
        Dim repo As ILancelotLabEntities

        context = _context.GetContext(contextId)
        repo = context.RepositoryContext

        result = repo.AnomalyProducts.ToList.Where(Function(p) p.IsExcluded).Any


        Return result

    End Function
```

But by this way i need to load all **AnomalyProducts** from Database. It take a long time just to get finally a boolean.

I think Expression Tree can help me, but i am not able to do that.

some help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you do `repo.AnomalyProducts.Where(Function(p) p.WholesalerProductCode = _excludedChar).Any()`?

Comment: @Arnold Because exclusion critera may change in the future, and exclusion test "IsExcluded" is call on many point in the program. So when critera will change i don't want read all of my code to track it.

Answer (score 2):

You can only do that with data on memory.
When you put some linq inside the Where (or any other) clause, entity framework will translate that to T-SQL.

This can't be translated to any T-SQL:

```
repo.AnomalyProducts.Where(Function(p) p.IsExcluded).Any
```

This can (because you're getting all data in memory:

```
repo.AnomalyProducts.ToList.Where(Function(p) p.IsExcluded).Any
```

To minimize effort, you could create a Expression (that is what the Where clause expects) and use that. This will only minimize the amount of places you'll have to copy and paste your code.

```
Dim exp As Expression(Of Func(Of AnomalyProduct, Boolean)) = Function(a) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.WholesalerProductCode) AndAlso a.WholesalerProductCode <> _excludedChar
repo.AnomalyProducts.Where(exp).Any
```

I havent tested it, but it should work just fine.

Comment: Should you want to, you can also let your `IsExcluded` method return the above expression.

Comment: @jessehouwing How would you use that? `.Where(SomeClass.IsExcluded())`? That doesn't feel right.

Comment: When it's in the same class you can use `.Where(x => IsExcluded(x))` or probably even `.Where(IsExcluded)`. You could also create a class with a proper name such as `ProductFunctions` and use the `ProductFunctions.IsExcluded` as you've proposed.

Comment: The important thing is return the expression, and not the result itself.